# How to make shared_ptrs work with different threads?

Tags: c++, c++11

lets say i have this code in main:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> command = std::make_shared<std::string>();
std::atomic<bool> done(true);
std::thread videoShow;

while (1) {
        std::getline(cin, *command);
        std::cout << *command;
        if ((*command).find("video") != std::string::npos) {
            if ((*command).find("start") != std::string::npos && done) {

                videoShow = std::thread(Video::showFrames, command, std::ref(done));
            }
        }
}
```

and this code in the function Video::showFrames:

```
void showFrames(std::shared_ptr<std::string> command, std::atomic<bool>& isDone){
     isDone = false;
     while (1) {
        std::cout << "this is command" << *command;
}
}
```

why if i write the command "video start" the output is:

```
this is command video start (first call to std::cout in main)
this is command
this is command ...
```

why is the call to *command in the 4th line of the function showFrames not working?

Comment: What happens next with `command` in the original thread after you started the new thread?...

Comment: How sure are you that `std::getline(cin, *command);` was successful? The program does not check.

Comment: nothing, the loop continues and calls std::getline() again

Comment: @kreaon And what does the call to `getline` do with the `std::string` object that the shared pointer refers to? The point is: You are modifying the string object while the other thread tries to read it. That is a data race and causes UB.

Comment: You have a data race. `shared_ptr` isn't thread-safe for the pointed-to data, only the pointer and ref counting itself.

Comment: On the base level, I see no synchronization in the code whatsoever.  That in itself is a red flag with respect to multithreaded programming and seeing things "not working".  It looks like single-threaded thinking being applied to a multi-threaded program, that that hardly works out.

Comment: You likely wanted a *local* `std::string` object for `std::getline()` to read into, and then pass a *copy* of that string to the `std::thread` for processing. In which case, there is no need to *share* the `std::string` across thread boundaries at all. On top of that, `showFrames` looks like a class method.  Is it a `static` method?  If not, it needs a `this` object to act on, but no such object is being passed to the `std::thread`, which will corrupt the parameters that `showFrames` receives

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I think it's a namespaced function (hence `Video::showFrames` and not `&Video::showFrames`). Thankfully, a missing object argument would be a compiler error too, so hard to miss.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to reassign `videoShow` with a new thread every iteration: the second assignment will result in `std::terminate` being called, since there's an active thread associated with the object...

Comment: @kreaon subsequent loop iterations create a new thread only if `isDone` is true. Which `showFrames` sets to false, and doesn't reset to true, so presumably there would never be another thread created.  Although, in this code, there is a *small* window of oppurtunity where multiple threads *could* be created, because of a race condition on `isDone`. The loop should reset `isDone` to false *before* creating the thread, not wait for the thread to reset it. Then the race will be gone

Comment: @kreaon even so, you still have a race on `isDone=false` when starting the thread, so multiple loop iterations *could potentially* see `isDone=true` and create more than 1 thread before any thread has been able to set `isDone=false`. So best to move `isDone=false` into the loop instead to eliminate the race. Of course, using an `atomic<bool>` in this manner isn't the best option to begin with. Consider using a `std::conditional_variable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of scary code to me. Your main is sitting their loading strings. Your worker thread is doing a fast-loop.

But the thread start up takes time. So let's say line 2 of your file has your video start string in it. Great. You spawn a thread. And then you immediately go do a fresh getline, trashing the old string you just read, before the thread has a chance to use it.

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, but I see no reason to use the shared pointer. Just pass the string by value (let it get copied) and be done with it, it seems to me.

Comment: if i change command in the main loop, does the value of command also change in the thread scope?

Comment: @kreaon In your original code presented, yes it does. But if `command` is no longer a `shared_ptr`, then no it won't, the thread will receive its own local copy of the string that is independent of `command`

Comment: what im trying to accomplish is to have a function running in parallel with main, and that continously checks on the string command to see if it has changed value. That change should occur in main with each std::getline(cin, command)

Comment: @kreaon That is not a good design choice, there are better ways to handle notifications across threads. But if you really want to go with that approach, you need to protect the `std::string` from concurrent access by multiple threads, and using `std::shared_ptr` alone won't offer that protection.

Comment: is there a way with single-threading to achieve what im looking for?

Comment: @kreaon You can't really do parallel processing in a single-threaded code. Well, you can multiplex asynchronous operations, I suppose (do a little of this, then a little of that, then check if user input is ready, and repeat), but user input doesn't lend itself well to that approach, at least not the way standard C++ does user input. There are platform-specific ways to do asynchronous user input without threading. But, for what you have shown, there is no problem using threads, you just need to use thread-safe logic, but the code you have presented is not wholly thread-safe, it has issues.

Comment: could you please show me how to make the code thread-safe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243304/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-kreaon).